# Unresolved reference: NavArgs after added some arguments to destination

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components, android-safe-args

I'm working on a small project and trying to use the new navigation architecture components. When i'm trying to add some arguments to a destination i got "Unresolved reference: NavArgs" error.

I followed this guide https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data#kotlin
and already added

`classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha11"`

to my project gradle file and also added

`apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'`

to my app gradle file.

As seen in the guide above i want to use `val args: AddKittenFragmentArgs by navArgs()` to get the passed arguments. But `navArgs()` isn't recognized.

Also `NavArgs` in the generated code isn't resolved.

```
data class MyFragmentArgs(val argOne: String? = "\"\"", val argTwo: String? = "\"\"") : NavArgs
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the documentation on that very page:

> When using the `-ktx` dependencies, Kotlin users can also use the by navArgs() property delegate to access arguments.

Make sure you are following the [Adding Components documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#navigation) and using the `navigation-fragment-ktx` dependency:

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha11"
```

Answer (score 18):

In my case i typed the argument Name starting by a capital letter

```
        <argument
            android:name="MyArgument" // changed it to myArgument fix the problem
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="false" />
```

Answer (score 11):

i had the same problem and i solved this by doing following steps

1. `Build -> Clean Project`
2. delete argument from `nav_graph.xml` file
3. create new argument
4. `Build -> Rebuild Project`
5. set the argument

```
val action: NavDirections = AreThereAnyDecayedTeethInTheAreaOfPainFragmentDirections
                .actionAreThereAnyDecayedTeethInTheAreaOfPainFragmentToResultFragment(
                    finalresult = "somethings"
                )
```

6. use this argument on FragmentDest

```
        arguments.let {
            binding.board.text = ResultFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it!!).finalresult
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem until I realized the navigation component's project dependencies were using a different version than the one specified by the plugin (in the classpath).

i.e. In the project's **build.gradle**

```
classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta01'
```

in the app **build.gradle**

```
// Navigation
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:'+ rootProject.navigationVersion
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:' + rootProject.navigationVersion
```

where **navigationVersion** was

```
ext {
   ...
   navigationVersion = "1.0.0-alpha08"
}
```

lint doesn't tell you there's an update to a library when the dependency is interpolated.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by doing `Clean Project` from `Build` menu of Android Studio.

Go to Menu : `Build` >> `Clean Project`

Comment: I also had all the solutions mentioned above in place thought this is hat solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue I used "setStartDestination(.." and now it works, instead of using the property access syntax i.e "startDestination=..."

Comment: Same with me i used setStartDestination() instead of startDestination it works.

Comment: I bumped the navigation library from 2.3.0 to 2.5.0 and had to replace the property access syntax to use the setter function and started getting "Unresolved reference: FooBarActivityArgs"

Comment: @GauriGadkari were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I need to added this it in my build.gradle (app)

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest release version 1.0.0 seems to have fixed this issue. Just change the navigation dependency version to `1.0.0` along with adding the `-ktx` dependencies as mentioned in other answers and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

just fyi if you want to pass `String` your argType should be `string` instead of String.

```
 app:argType="string"
```

Comment: Was the the issue for OP?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, but it can be an issue for someone else

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Make it sure that your `AndroidManifest.xml` is containing  package name like that -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app">
```

**Step 2:** Use the latest version from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_25_2).

**Step 3:** `Clean build` the project.

**Step 4:** `Rebuild` the project.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue adding id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' this plugin in the corresponding gradle file fixed the issue. We need to clean build once this plugin is added.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved when I inserted the code inside fragment class:

```
class UpdateNoteFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_update_note) {
   lateinit var binding: FragmentUpdateNoteBinding
   lateinit var viewModel: NotasViewModel
   lateinit var notaSeleccionada:Nota
   val args:UpdateNoteFragmentArgs by navArgs()
   ....
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).