# Why do I get the error Unresolved reference: navArgument when I run the end branch of Android sample project?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I run the *main* branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab) well in Android Studio.

My Android Studio is 2020.3.1 Path 4, and Gradle version is displayed as Image 1.

**Image 1**
[image]

But I get the following error when I try to compile the *end* branch of the project.

*E:\Android_Studio_Sample\android-compose-codelabs\NavigationCodelab\app\src\main\java\com\example\compose\rally\RallyActivity.kt: (31, 36): Unresolved reference: navArgument*

How can I fix it?

BTW, I have read [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354034/unresolved-reference-navargs-after-added-some-arguments-to-destination).

I get the following error after I added `implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0"` to the *end* branch of the project

*Your project has set `android.useAndroidX=true`, but configuration `debugRuntimeClasspath` still contains legacy support libraries, which may cause runtime issues.
This behavior will not be allowed in Android Gradle plugin 8.0.*

And more, I  still get the error *"Unresolved reference: navArgument"* when I added `android.enableJetifier=true`.

**Added content**

The project can run when I replace `import androidx.navigation.compose.navArgument` with `import androidx.navigation.navArgument`, could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

navArgument was moved to the androidx.navigation package

```
package androidx.navigation

/**
 * Construct a new [NavArgument]
 */
public fun navArgument(
    name: String,
    builder: NavArgumentBuilder.() -> Unit
): NamedNavArgument = NamedNavArgument(name, NavArgumentBuilder().apply(builder).build())

/**
 * Construct a named [NavArgument] by using the [navArgument] method.
 */
public class NamedNavArgument internal constructor(

    /**
     * The name the argument is associated with
     */
    public val name: String,

    /**
     * The [NavArgument] associated with the name
     */
    public val argument: NavArgument
) {
    /**
     * Provides destructuring access to this [NamedNavArgument]'s [name]
     */
    public operator fun component1(): String = name

    /**
     * Provides destructuring access to this [NamedNavArgument]'s [argument]
     */
    public operator fun component2(): NavArgument = argument
}
```